# Unable to get only date from JSON date string in swift

Tags: json, swift, nsdateformatter

the JSON is like below

```
"user": {
        "id": 160,
        "date": "2021-04-13 16:30:06",
```

now i need to show only date in label, if i add like below.. i am getting total string

```
 self?.dateLabel.text = user?["date"] as? String
```

o/p: 2021-04-13 16:30:06

i need only 2021-04-13 in self?.dateLabel.text

so i tried

```
var dateString = user?["date"] as? String
var dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString!)
 print(date)
```

o/p: getting nil

how to show only date in label from JSON date string.. please do help

Comment: Change the `dateFormat` of your `DateFormatter` to `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` to get the `Date` object and then use another `DateFormatter` to print only the information that you want from this object.

Comment: @gcharita, can u show me in answer.. i am unable to understand pls

Comment: Or you could just split the string here, `if let dateString = user?["date"] as? String, let date = dateString.split(separator: " ").first {   self?.dateLabel.text = date }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `DateFormatter` in order to get the `Date` object out of the string. To do that you need a date format that matches this string, like this:

```
var dateString = "2021-04-13 16:30:06"
var dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
```

After that, you need to modify your `DateFormatter` with the date format that you want to display:

```
if let date = date {
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    let displayText = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    print(displayText)
}
```

Of course, you generally need to know at which timezone this date is represented in the JSON or else you will end up with a wrong date.

To set the time zone in a `DateFormatter` use `timeZone` property. For example to set GMT timezone:

```
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
```